# Moodle role permission 'mod/certificate:manage' what ability does it give?

Tags: moodle, totara

I would like to know what are the abilities provided when this moodle role permission 'mod/certificate:manage' if allowed for a role. Please, help. And how can i find out?
I don't have anything here https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Capabilities/mod/certificate:manage
Is there a specific place to look for?

Answer (score 0):

To get an exact idea of what that role is used for (or any other not documented one) you need to look at the code. Basically look within the directory of the mod certificate plugin for things like `require_capability('mod/certificate:manage'` or `has_capability('mod/certificate:manage'`.

In general, it is a common practice in Moodle to call `manage` to the capability that checks and allows for the most "manager-like" actions, the kind of actions you would allow to editing teachers and managers of a course (like, for example, manipulating settings of an instance of the activity)... but it is entirely up to the plugin developer to follow that "tradition" or not, so to look at the code is still advised.